# Highlight second level li in navigation bar when hovering over third level li

Tags: jquery, css, navigation

I'm looking to highlight the second level parent of a navigation bar when hovering over any of it's children; the top level has completely different styling so doesn't apply to what I'm trying to do, so when I hover over any of the third level items I want to style the second level. I understand javascript/jquery is the way to go for this so as my skills aren't up to scratch I've hit a brick wall.

Here's my standard html navigation structure:

```
<nav class="primary-navigation">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="#">TOP LEVEL</a>
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">SECOND LEVEL</a>
                     <ul>
                         <li><a href="#">THIRD LEVEL</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">THIRD LEVEL</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">THIRD LEVEL</a></li>                    
                     </ul>
                 </li>
             </ul>
         </li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

I've been trying to work without classes, but I've been having trouble with selecting the li items without them, ideally if it's possible I'd like to learn how to do it without them.

Here's how far I've gotten so far, but it seems to add the 'highlighted' class to all the children as well, but I just want to apply it to the parent item!

```
$('THIRD LEVEL').mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).parent().closest('SECOND LEVEL').addClass('highlighted');
  }).mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).parent().closest('SECOND LEVEL').removeClass('highlighted');
  });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: why are you trying to work without classes?

Comment: No reason in particular, just to keep my code as small as possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you use the highlight class on the complete `li` element. If you add `highlighted` only to the link it works.

```
$('.third').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('a.second').addClass('highlighted');
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('a.second').removeClass('highlighted');
});
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/VqcKu/7/

Comment: Np. If its answering your question, just accept the answer by clicking the green check under the counter, to indicate for others that you question is answered to you.

Answer (score 0):

If this is only going to be applied at the third level, this should suffice:

```
$('.primary-navigation ul ul ul li').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('highlighted');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('highlighted');  
    }
);
```

Comment: That was not the question. The problem is that the third-level is also highlighted as it is surrounded by the second-level `li` tag.

Comment: then this is most probably a problem of css styling. Can you post the relevant css? I would guess the child li is inheriting css attributes from the parent li. In the attributes specified in the .hilight class need to be overwritten with an explicit definition in the li styling.